# Node Docker Image supporting node --harmony

Tags: node.js, docker

I am creating apis in es6. As I try to dockerize, I am getting the error below -->

```
System error: exec: "node --harmony": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Here is my dockerfile listing

```
FROM node:5.5
COPY . /src
RUN cd /src; npm install
EXPOSE  9095
WORKDIR /src
RUN pwd
CMD ["node --harmony", "cluster.js"]
```

Comment: Did you try `["node", "--harmony", "cluster.js"]` ?

Comment: Right on money - Thanks Felix.
Quick question is 5.5 is right one to use in production >

Comment: Should be fine if you intend to upgrade more often, otherwise use 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note: I have no idea about docker)

Looking at the error message and the syntax for declaring the command, it seems that every command line parameter has to be specified as separate element, so you should be doing

```
CMD ["node", "--harmony", "cluster.js"]
```